Best way to 3D model image reference
What would be the preferred method to model the ears and furry cheeks?
I tried duplicating and extruding the vertices but could not cover the fur. I then tried duplicating the faces, which is a little better but I am not sure how to make it look like the image.  Finally, a plane mesh w/sub modifier. I will keep trying this way but wanted to know if there is a better way to do this.
I’ve seen Ryan King use the plane mesh on his butterfly tutorial.  I have also tried following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pjVEHODkjhA, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_s7qh74R-4Y, and https://www.cgarena.com/freestuff/tutorials/misc/headmodeling/index.html but I'm the challenge I am having is understanding how to extrude the cube mesh to model the fur and ears around the reference image.






Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

For something like an ear that round you probably want to start with a circle of 6 or 8 vertices and make a sort of bowl shape. Then you'd have to connect it to the rest of the head geometry.

Your face probably need a lot more geometry than that to connect properly.
Making fur is a whole nother can of worms tho. You are not going to be able to make fur but using simple, subdivided geometry like that.
For something like this I think what you'd want to do is sculpt the base model and stylized fur in sculpt mode.
Alternatively, you can make the base, smooth model with subdivided geometry and then make the fur with hair particles.
I don't know what you want the model for so I cant tell what the best approach is but you should look up some tutorials on sculpting and hair physics with blender if you want to do this kinda of stuff imo
